# Will the Java Compact Profiles actually reduce memory footprint?

Tags: java

My understanding of Java Class loading is that its lazy loaded. Thus if you have a bunch of unused jars shipped with a Java application they will only waste disk space and not actually consume memory. However it seems to be implied on various Oracle blogs/documentation that compact profiles will actually reduce memory footprint ([here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/a_first_look_at_compact) and [here](http://vitalflux.com/why-when-use-java-8-compact-profiles/)).

To make it an easy yes or no question that is not subjective:

**If I make a "hello world!" Java application (ie only using System.out) will it actually have a smaller runtime memory footprint when run by a compact1 profile instead of the full SE?** (I would test this myself but having trouble compiling the compact profiles).

Comment: Yes.  With compact profiles, the entire JRE is not loaded into memory.  Only the required run time libraries are loaded into memory.  While the application classes are lazy loaded, the JRE classes are loaded into memory when the JRE is started.

Comment: Holy crap! So basically everything in `rt.jar` is loaded regardless of whether its used or not? So it just loads all those classes into memory including corba and rmi crap? Is that only specific to `rt.jar`? And why would they do that? Is the preloading better for performance? Do you have a link that says the rt.jar is fully loaded on init?

Comment: You'll have to ask Oracle (or Sun) why.  I suspect the decision was to increase startup time rather than have an application stop and wait for corba classes to be loaded, as an example.  Personal computer memory was cheap and plentiful back in 1995.  Smart phones were a decade away.

Comment: I found this [quote](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html): "Whenever a new JVM is started by typing java MyMainClass, the "bootstrap class loader" is responsible for loading key Java classes like java.lang.Object and other runtime code into memory first. The runtime classes are packaged inside of the JRE\lib\rt.jar file. We cannot find the details of the bootstrap class loader in the Java documentation, since this is a native implementation. For the same reason, the behavior of the bootstrap class loader will also differ across JVMs."

Comment: It's been my experience that the Oracle JVM loads all of the rt.jar classes and all of the ext classes when the JVM is started.  You can measure memory consumption with your "Hello World" application.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have never seen a JVM do that. You can trace the class loading process. It loads them lazily just like anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, compact profiles will reduce memory footprint.

During the JVM startup several things happen:

- native libraries loaded into memory
- rt.jar loaded into memory
- referenced libraries loaded into memory only when they actually used

Different compact profiles include different set of technologies. Thus reducing number of loaded objects into memory. You could check what exactly loaded into memory using the command:

```
pmap <jvm pid>
```

On my raspberry pi with profile compact1 and default heap size I've got 12Mb.

Answer (score 0):

There is three compact profile, according to the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/tech/compact-profiles-overview-2157132.html):

**Profile compact1 loads** Core (java.lang.*), Security, Serialization, Networking, Ref Objects, Regular Expressions, Date and Time, Input/Output, Collections, Logging, Concurrency, Reflection, JAR, ZIP, Versioning, Internationalization, JNI, Override Mechanism, Extension Mechanism, Scripting

**Profile compact 2 adds** JDBC, RMI, XML, JAXP

**Profile compact 3 adds** Security (kerberos, acl, and sasl), JMX, JNDI, XML JAXP2, Management, Instrumentation

These profiles can be activated throug the `-profile` option of `javac`.

Note also that `System.out` is part of the bootstrap classes according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html#bootclass):

> Bootstrap classes are the classes that implement the Java 2 Platform.
>   Bootstrap classes are in the rt.jar and several other jar files in the
>   jre/lib directory.

and this may interssed you

> It is very unlikely that you will need to redefine the bootstrap class
>   path. The nonstandard option, **-Xbootclasspath**, allows you to do so in
>   those rare cicrcumstances in which it is necessary to use a different
>   set of core classes.

So in conclusion, to answer your specific question using compact1 profile won't gives you a smaller memory footprint when running "Hello world" because `System.out` is in the bootstrap classes but using the **-Xbootclasspath** could maybe do the tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCaBno_Euqk&feature=youtu.be) link [from](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/tech/compact-profiles-overview-2157132.html).

It shows Java8 allows to create JRE of different sizes using profiles selection and we can start that specific runtime to reduce memory footprint. And which profile your application is needed can be identified via `jdeps` and based on that you can start your minimal runtime.

[jrecreate](https://www.baeldung.com/jrecreate) is a tool part of Embedded Java Development Kit for creating different profile jre.